# phonegap - I came back after 5 months and I can not build a new version

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

Hi After 5 months I was with version phonegap build 3.4.0 I saw that phonegap build build is currently version 3.6.3 
What I do not understand, I sent a new version with

```
<preference name = "phonegap-version" value = "3.6.3" />
```

But it changes me the name of the application to "PG Build App" and not showing me my app, it displays a list of links. 
What should I do?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please paste your code in configuration file here? I am doing update for my cordova app these days. Even from cordova 2.6 to 3.6.3, the app name has not been changed.

Comment: What code you want the config.xml?

Comment: (1) Have you tried any other version on PG Build, for example, 3.5. (2) Paste related code for your app id and name here from your config.xml

Comment: 3.5.0 does not work well
ID: 1205248
Name: Rafael Smith

Comment: How about paste your config.xml here for us to check it in detail? According your description so far, I could not locate the root.